# Samsung Galaxy Note 2 keeps rebooting

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, samsung, samsung-galaxy-note-2

I got a Samsung Galaxy Note 2 now for more than 2 years. Since a week my phone reboots without an error. And when it reboots then it will keep rebooting, my phone can´t startup anymore. I need to remove the battery and charge it a little (even though my battery is 50% full) before it can startup normally.

I already tried to factory reset my phone but this didn't help.

Is there a way to determine why my phone keeps doing this or do I need to accept that my phone is broken?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to get angry with mobile. I also had this same problem because of two reasons

1. **OS is not compatible with the device**(i installed DN5 ROM on [electron-team.com](http://electron-team.com/galaxy-note/note-2/ditto-note-4/sm-n7100/))
2. Mobile **batter's life time** expired.

---

**Why 01??**

When your OS is not suit to your Mobile it will hangs. So when its hangs it will automatically restart your device. This will happen when  using FB long time or some high end apps.

**Why 02??**

When your battery life is end, your battery not keep actual percentage of capacity. When you plug it shows *Battery Full*. but in 2-3 Minutes it will get down. As well as battery lost dealing with mobile OS. and it will be get reboot as usual.

---

after fixing those now my device is not reboots  or any other problem.

Find your firmware version on [Sammobile Website](http://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/) by searching on search field.

Comment: can you elaborate on point 01 :)? When an 'OS' is not compatible with the device it will refuse to boot up. I agree with your second point though - a faulty battery might lead to these problems

Comment: @benjaminS exactly first one is the problem for  reboot of my mobile :)

Comment: @benjaminS when you use same DN5 of above link you can easily understand. Cz i have **hands on experience now.**

Comment: I don't think its 01 because it started when I used the regular Android. Now I am using cyanogenmod wich got a lower Android version but it still happens. But it could be the battery I might buy a new battery to test it out.

Comment: use Samsung based OS. i also tired with installing cyanogenmod and Resurrection Remix. No use. Try with above link

Comment: I used a Samsung based OS for the whole time also when it started. So I don't think it is the OS. And I got another question. Why would my phone reboot if the battery is damaged or something. I think it would rather just shutdown and don't startup automatically.

Comment: @JellevanEs actually what ever im telling you is some thing like magic for you. i cant force to do. But this is my solution i fixed for my device. Without questioning how about trying